# What would be the best way to create association in a list (array) of arbitrary things?

Tags: java, json, logic, nlp

I'm making a word-definition quiz app, and my list of words and their definitions is in JSON, structured like this:

```
"words": [
        {
            "word": "rescind",
            "type": "verb",
            "definition": "to take back, repeal as in a rule or policy"
        },
        {
            "word": "curtail",
            "type": "verb",
            "definition": "to reduce or lessen"
        },
```

etc, etc.

In the quiz, you're given one randomly picked word, and five definitions to choose from. Like a standardized multiple-choice test.

Now, a problem I'm starting to see is that I have words with very similar meanings. I currently have the 4 wrong definitions picked randomly from the list, but to avoid confusion, I want to avoid picking definitions that are similar to the correct choice.

How should I go about creating this "similarity" map? One solution I thought of would be this:

```
        {
            "word": "avid",
            "type": "adjective",
            "definition": "extremely excited about, enthusiastic about",
            "similar to": [
                "ardent",
                "fervent"
            ]
        },
```

But I realized this solution kinda sucks because I have to go to each other word and implement the same list, and it'll get *real* bulky to edit when I end up adding lots and lots of words.

So what do you guys think would be the best solution?

Answer (score 3):

A simple first approach would be to create a `Word` class with fields.

Make sure you override [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) using the "word" field (I calle dit "value" to distinguish it from the class name) (see below):

```
public class Word {
    private final String value;
    private final String type;
    private final String definition;
    private final List<Word> synonymns = new ArrayList<Word>();

    public Word(String value, String type, String definition) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    // equals() and hashCode() based on the value field
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return value.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         return obj instanceof Word && ((Word)obj).value.equals(value);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }
    public List<Word> getSynonymns() {
        return synonymns;
    }
}
```

Implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()` based on the value field means you can prevent duplicates by using a Set:

```
Set<Word> words = new HashSet<Word>(); // wont allow two Word objects with the same value
```

You can use the return value from [`Set.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29), which true if the set did not already contain the specified element, to check that the word being added is in fact unique:

```
Word word = new Word("duplicate", "adjective", "another copy");
if (!words.add(word)) {
    // oops! set already contained that word
}
```

---

If you wanted to add special sauce, make the `type` an enum:

```
public enum PartOfSpeach {
    NOUN,
    VERB, // in USA "verb" includes all nouns, because any noun can be "verbed"
    ADJECTIVE,
    ADVERB
}
```

You may consider allowing words to belong to multiple types:

- bark: verb: what dogs do
- bark: noun: what covers a tree

In fact, you may consider having multiple meanings per Word:

```
public class Meaning {
    PartOfSpeach p;
    String definition;
    List<Word> synonyms; // synonyms belong to a particular *meaning* of a Word.
}
```

Comment: I actually do have a Word class, and that's the implementation I have right now. I can just foresee problems if I (well, not me, I won't be doing the adding) add words a few months from now, and I don't remember already having similar words, or if I forget to update every individual word with the new synonyms. This works, but there's gotta be a better way.

Comment: When adding, you can always add a function to check to see if it already exists first. I believe it's also possible to make a function to add synonyms if you designate which words need adding.

Comment: Whoa, that hashcode stuff looks really promising. Thanks! This might be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah - it's *really* important. Read the javadoc (linked in my answer) to read up on hashCode and equals and how they should align with each other. Knowing this stuff will make you a better programmer and help you get a job, because this is a common interview question!